# Padding between the image and the border

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-page

I am **developing** a `facebook fanpage`. I am having problem with **the space between the main image** that I am using and the border of the page. I just want the image to appear and take **all of the space** on the fanpage. 
Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Nikah4Life</title>
<script type="text/javascript">window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.Canvas.setSize();}// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()function sizeChangeCallback() {FB.Canvas.setSize();}</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="text-align:center; width:532px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img id="Image-Maps_8201108311953149" src="sponsors.jpg" usemap="#Image-Maps_8201108311953149" border="0" width="400" height="700" alt="" />
<map id="_Image-Maps_8201108311953149" name="Image-Maps_8201108311953149">
<area shape="rect" coords="53,6,356,33" href="http://www.nikah4life.com/" target="_blank" alt="" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="146,650,259,691" href="http://www.nikah4life.com/" target="_blank" alt="" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="59,269,123,303" href="http://twitter.com/#!/Nikah4Life" target="_blank" alt="" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="165,269,236,303" href="http://www.youtube.com/nikah4life"  target="_blank" alt="" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="268,269,349,303" href="http://www.nikah4life.com/contact.php" target="_blank" alt="" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="8,328,179,397" href="http://harunyahya.co.uk/"  target="_blank" alt="" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="134,396,291,461" href="http://www.linksdisti.com/"  target="_blank" alt="" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="222,324,395,399" href="http://www.zainbhikha.com/index.htm" alt=""  target="_blank" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="245,488,387,625" href="http://www.youtube.com/nikah4life" alt="" target="_blank" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="361,426,395,459" href="http://www.technology-arena.com/" alt="" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="8,426,40,459" href="http://www.technology-arena.com/" alt="" title=""    />
</map>
</div>
         <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
 appId  : 'your APP ID Goes Here',
 status : true, // check login status
 cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
 xfbml  : true// parse XFBML
 });

 FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(7);

 </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
Changing the alignment from middle to left made it work. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: The image is having a white area of about 30 px on the right and left of it. It is using 60px. I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas for Pages is supposed to have a border on it. I don't think it can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your css

> body {
>                   width:520px;
>                   margin:0;
>                   padding:0;
>                   border:0;
>                   overflow:hidden;
>                   }